# clojure.data.json/write-str: specifying a key function for placing values into aggregate arrays

Tags: json, clojure

Suppose I have a simple map, `example-map`:

```
(def example-map {"s" {"f" "g"} 
                  "m" {"r" "q"}})
```

I can use `clojure.data.json/write-str` to JSON-ify this map as such:

```
(clojure.data.json/write-str example-map) =>
"{\"s\":{\"f\":\"g\"},\"m\":{\"r\":\"q\"}}"
```

I'd like to conditionally place some of the values into lists according to the value of their keys.

`write-str` provides an optional `:key-fn`, which applies some function to key value pairs. For example, the desired function might specify that all values associated with entries that match `"s"` are placed in lists.

```
(clojure.data.json/write-str example-map :key-function desired-function) =>
"{\"s\":[{\"f\":\"g\"}],\"m\":{\"r\":\"q\"}}"
```

Does anyone know how to specify such a key function that checks for membership of a key in a set and places the values associated with members into an array rendered in the output JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like your previous question, this is not a job for the JSON parser. You don't need to rely on write-time features of your JSON library to adjust the shape of your JSON maps. Instead, you have a fully functional Turing complete language at your disposal: Clojure! If the maps don't already look the way you want them to be output, then write a function that takes one Clojure map as input and produces a different one as output; then ask your JSON library to write the output map, without any special rules for fiddling with the output.

Now, as it happens this particular JSON library *does* provide an option named `value-fn` (not `key-function` as you claim) to let you modify a value in a map based on its key. So you could use that, in which case you simply need to write a function with a signature like:

```
(fn [k v]
  (...compute new value...))
```

There are many ways you could write such a function, but they are all entirely divorced from your JSON parser. If you need help writing it, mention some specific things you need help with, so you can get a clear explanation for the part of the process that is actually giving you trouble.